# How to make ggplot2 keep unused levels on data subset

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart, levels

My problem is clearly not new, but I haven't been able to find my exact coding question answered. I am working from a subset of my data (available [here](https://figshare.com/s/ace5b44bc12394a7c46d)) and have been trying all possible combinations of `scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)` and `scale_fill_discrete(drop=FALSE)` to try to get `ggplot2` to include a space where the bar would be for Chipmunks (n=0 for event "CF" - *n.b.* this corresponds to the variable "forage" in the data).

The code I am using is as follows:

```
require(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

#excluding MICROs from my plot
ggplot(data[data$sps=="MAMO" | data$sps=="TAST" | data$sps=="MUVI"|    data$sps=="MUXX" | data$sps=="TAHU",], 
      aes(sps, fill=forage))+geom_bar(position="dodge") +
    labs(x = "Species", y = "Number of observations") +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Marmot","American Mink", "Weasel Spp.", "Red squirrel", "Chipmunk")) +
    theme_classic() + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#000000", "#666666", "#999999","#CCCCCC"), name = "Event")
```

I then get a plot like this one:
[image: Plot]

When I add `scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)` I get this:[image: Problem Plot]
What the code appears to be doing is including my previously excluded MICRO data (hence everything gets shifted over one after Marmots and Chipmunks still only have 3 bars).

When I try `scale_fill_discrete(drop = FALSE)` the resulting plot doesn't change at all from the first plot presented. When I try both `scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)` and `scale_fill_discrete(drop = FALSE)` the plot looks like the second plot presented.

I figure I can manually go and make a small table with the frequencies for each level (Event), but I would like to first try to code it properly in R.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what I could add/change in my code to do this?

**Update:**
I tried the code suggested below:

```
df1 %>% 
  filter(sps != "MICRO") %>% 
  group_by(sps) %>% 
  count(forage) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  complete(sps, forage, fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(sps, n)) + geom_col(aes(fill = forage), position = "dodge") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Marmot","American Mink", "Weasel Spp.", "Red squirrel", "Chipmunk")) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#000000", "#666666", "#999999","#CCCCCC"), name = "Event") + 
  labs(x = "Species", y = "Number of observations")
```

The resulting plot has the space (yay!) but still has an empty space for where MICRO would be:

[image: second attempt]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that a count of zero is not generated for sps = TAST, forage = CF. You can create that count using `tidyr::complete`. I've also added some `dplyr` functions to make the code cleaner. Assuming that your data frame is named `df1` (as opposed to `data`, which is a base function name so not a good choice):

UPDATED: with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to address issues in comments.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- read.table("data.txt", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1 %>% 
  filter(sps != "MICRO") %>% 
  group_by(sps) %>% 
  count(forage) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  complete(sps, forage, fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(sps, n)) + geom_col(aes(fill = forage), position = "dodge") +
    scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Marmot","American Mink", "Weasel Spp.", "Red squirrel", "Chipmunk")) + 
    theme_classic() + 
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#000000", "#666666", "#999999","#CCCCCC"), name = "Event") + 
    labs(x = "Species", y = "Number of observations")
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Or just `data.frame(table(...)`, e.g. `ggplot(subset(data.frame(table(data)), sps != 'MICRO'), aes(sps, Freq, fill = forage)) + 
    geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
    labs(x = "Species", y = "Number of observations", fill = "Event")+
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Marmot","American Mink", "Weasel Spp.", "Red squirrel", "Chipmunk")) +
    theme_classic() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#000000", "#666666", "#999999","#CCCCCC"))`

Comment: @neilfws I literally copied and pasted your code (after changing the name of my data and loading the required packages) and I get the space, but sps=MICRO is still in my plot. I have put the figure in my above question with the code. The version of R I am using is 3.3.2. Why would it work for you, but not for me?

Comment: If you use the data from your link (as data frame `df1`) and the code in my answer, you should get the same result. Double-check the data and the code.

Comment: @alistaire When I try your code, I get the following error: "Error in table(data) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements".

Comment: @neilfws I downloaded the data I posted (to try again) and copy and paste the code and the figure doesn't look like yours. Is there any code you ran beforehand that might be why this is happening?

Comment: No there isn't. I'm afraid you'll just have to figure out what you are doing differently :) Trust me, there is something different, otherwise you'd be getting the same result. Try running everything up until the `ggplot`; you should see a 20x3 tibble with the zero count for TAST and no MICRO. If you don't, then the data source is different.

Comment: I think I know what your issue is. When you read the file `data.txt` using `read.table`, `sps` and `forage` were read in as factors. So the `filter` does not remove `MICRO`. Try this: `df1 <- read.table("data.txt", header = TRUE, stringsasFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: @neilfws Right. That makes sense. I have tried `df1 <- read.table("data.txt", header = TRUE, stringsasFactors = FALSE)` but I get the following error: `Error in read.table("/Users/april-martinig/Desktop/data.txt", header = TRUE,  : 
  unused argument (stringsasFactors = FALSE)`. I will keep fiddling with `stringsasFactors = FALSE` to see what the problem might be.

Comment: @neilfws I tried `df1 <- read.table("data.txt", header = TRUE, colClasses="character")` instead and this worked! Thank you for your help (and persistence) with this problem. It's much appreciated!

Comment: Good to hear! My apologies, I mistyped the argument. It is `stringsAsFactors`, upper-case 'A' in 'As'. But your argument works too.